# data and loop-dependency analysis with LLVM

Tags: dependencies, llvm, static-analysis, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

Does anyone know how can I do data-dependency/loop-dependency analysis with LLVM and clang?

Looking at the passes webpage [-da](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#da-dependence-analysis), apparently it has been mentioned that this pass is doing the job, but using this pass doesn't change anything in the output, neither the `./a.out` size nor the `.ll` IR-codes.

I was wondering if we can understand the WAR,RAW, etc and also other dependencies using LLVM platform.

Comment: The -da pass is an analysis pass and thus doesn't modify the IR. Anyway if you are trying to just do dependence analysis, why do you need to change the source?

Comment: I don't need to change the source code, just wanna see the output of the analysis.

Comment: I too have used it and according to my experience it does print dependencies between all memory operations, You may also try adding -debug option to opt to see what is going around

Comment: However I ended up writing my own dependency module because of my particular needs. You too might have to do that if you are looking to use that info

Answer (score 5):

`-da(dependency analysis)` is an analysis pass, analysis passes doesn't change bitcode, they just gather information to be used by the other analysis or transformation passes. So if you want to use its information, you should write a new transform and add "DependenceAnalysis" as a "RequiredAnalysis" to a virtual function named "getAnalysisUsage" inside your pass, then you will have "DependenceAnalysis" as an abject.